# A simple code to detect the permutation sign

Tags: algorithm

supposed I have an array of integers:

```
1 2 5 3 7 6
```

What is a simple enough algorithm that determines if this is an even or odd permutation of the numbers in sorted fashion (i.e. `1 2 3 5 6 7`)? Performance is not terribly important here; I'd rather have a simple code.

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/65938/16267

Comment: @hammar - This method requires sorting.

Comment: Am I missing something here? Why cant we just use the last two numbers? For any given n and n-2 long prefix, we have exactly 2 remaining permutation, no? So for every (n-2) prefix if the rest of the two numbers are sorted, then it is odd and not sorted, then it is even?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently determine the parity of a permutation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702782/efficiently-determine-the-parity-of-a-permutation)

Answer (score 7):

Simple Code(Assume n numbers are stored in array a):

```
int f()
{
    int cnt=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
            if (a[i]>a[j]) cnt++;
    return cnt%2;
}
```

If f() returns 0, then it is even permutation and returns 1, then it is odd.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia, the sign is determined by the number of inversions (pairs of elements out of order). That gives an O(n**2) algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement your own version of [Heap Sort Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) having a complexity of O(n log n) and counting the number of permutation in order to build your signature (I assume you know what I'm talking about).

Sample code:

```
public static void HeapSort(int[] input)
{
    //Build-Max-Heap
    int heapSize = input.Length;
    for (int p = (heapSize - 1) / 2; p >= 0; p--)
        MaxHeapify(input, heapSize, p);

    for (int i = input.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        //Swap
        int temp = input[i];
        input[i] = input[0];
        input[0] = temp;

        heapSize--;
        MaxHeapify(input, heapSize, 0);
    }
}

private static void MaxHeapify(int[] input, int heapSize, int index)
{
    int left = (index + 1) * 2 - 1;
    int right = (index + 1) * 2;
    int largest = 0;

    if (left < heapSize && input[left] > input[index])
        largest = left;
    else
        largest = index;

    if (right < heapSize && input[right] > input[largest])
        largest = right;

    if (largest != index)
    {
        int temp = input[index];
        input[index] = input[largest];
        input[largest] = temp;

        MaxHeapify(input, heapSize, largest);
    }
}
```

Comment: For counting inversions, a mergesort would be easier, methinks. But counting inversions with a sorting algorithm is the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple code that runs in O(nlogn), and tr[] is an array with all 0s in it initially.

```
int ans=0;
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    for(int j=a[i];j;j-=j&-j) ans+=tr[j];
    for(int j=a[i];j<=n;j+=j&-j) tr[j]++;
}
printf((n*(n-1)/2-ans)%2?"odd\n":"even");
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and done in python for when I inevitably need to find this again:

```
def is_even(p):

    if len(p) == 1:
        return True

    trans = 0

    for i in range(0,len(p)):
        j = i + 1

        for j in range(j, len(p)):
            if p[i] > p[j]: 
                trans = trans + 1

    return ((trans % 2) == 0)
```

Comment: thanks, I've slightly refactored your version [here](https://gist.github.com/lycantropos/217710b0afc40b3031762274275c204a)

Comment: So this makes use of the inversion definition. You count every single pair (i,j) such that i<j but p_i>p_j.

Answer (score 1):

See how [Sympy](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/combinatorics/permutations.py) does it. In a nutshell, here is how it works:

You can find the number of cycles, subtract it from the length of the array, take its parity, and then find the sign. Finding the number of cycles is O(N) by using a set or a boolean array to check visited values. All the other operations are O(1), so all in all, this new approach is O(N).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an O(n) answer.

```
(define (sign-of-permutation permutation)
  (define p (vector-copy permutation))
  (define l (vector-length p))
  (define q (make-vector l))
  (let iter ((i 0))
    (unless (= i l)
      (define x (vector-ref p i))
      (vector-set! q x i)
      (iter (+ i 1))))
  (printf "~s\n" p)
  (let iter ((i 0) (s 1))
    (if (= i l)
        s
        (let ((x (vector-ref p i)))
          (if (= i x)
              (iter (+ i 1) s)
              (let ((j (vector-ref q i)))
                (vector-swap! p i j)
                (printf "~s\n" p)
                (vector-swap! q x i)
                (iter (+ i 1) (- s))))))))
```

Here is an example.

```
> (define p (vector 3 4 2 0 1))
> (sign-of-permutation p)
#(3 4 2 0 1)
#(0 4 2 3 1)
#(0 1 2 3 4)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

The sign of the determinant of the permutation matrix for this vector should give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Decompose the permutation into a product of independent cycles. Odd cycles are odd. Even cycles are even. Add up.

Comment: Odd length cycles are even permutations. Even length cycles are odd permutations.