# Extracting Transposition Count from Return Tuple

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to determine whether a permutation is odd or even by counting the transpositions from a sort. Specifically, I'd like to use the int `b+c+d` in the attached code so that upon calling the `SortCount(A)` function it will give an output of either `True` or `False` based on whether that value is odd or even.

The tuple that is returned in the included code gives the sorted array and the number of transpositions required to sort that array from it's original configuration. I'm a bit new to using tuples, and programming in general, and am not sure how to make the transposition number available to perform the stated manipulation above. Manipulating `B, b+c+d` from the return line for `SortCount(A)` breaks the code. The code is attached.

```
def SortCount(A):
    l = len(A)
    if l > 1:
        n = l//2
        C = A[:n]
        D = A[n:]
        C, c = SortCount(A[:n])
        D, d = SortCount(A[n:])
        B, b = MergeCount(C,D)
        return B, b+c+d
    else:
        return A, 0

def MergeCount(A,B):
    count = 0
    M = []
    while A and B:
        if A[0] <= B[0]: 
          M.append(A.pop(0)) 
        else: 
          count += len(A)
          M.append(B.pop(0)) 
    M  += A + B     
    return M, count
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! I don't think this question is appropriate to this channel... it seems to be a programming task not really an issue.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702782/efficiently-determine-the-parity-of-a-permutation#20703469) gives a better algorithm to find the permutation's parity.

Comment: I don't see your problem. The code seems to work.

Comment: The code DOES work. However, I need to do more with the transposition count output from the SortCount(A) result. I want to take the b+c+d portion of that and generate a True/False Output when the function is called.  I'm looking for suggestions on how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 0):

this code will work fine.

```
def is_even(p):

    s=SortCount(p)
    return s[1]%2==0

def SortCount(p):

    l = len(p)
    if l > 1:
        n = l//2
        C = p[:n]
        D = p[n:]
        C, c = SortCount(p[:n])
        D, d = SortCount(p[n:])
        B, b = MergeCount(C,D)
        return B, b+c+d
    else:
        return p, 0

def MergeCount(p,B):

    count = 0
    M = []
    while p and B:
        if p[0] <= B[0]: 
          M.append(p.pop(0)) 
        else: 
          count += len(p)
          M.append(B.pop(0)) 
    M  += p + B     
    return M, count
```