# How can I generate the next permutation using the Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

How can I take a permutation *i* and generate the *(i+1)th* permutation with the Steinhaus-Johnson-Trotter (SJT) algorithm? There are solutions to generate **all** of the permutations using the SJT algorithm, but since the permutations follow a pattern, I want to generate the **next** permutation.

I attempted to write such an algorithm. However, for the permutation **4213**, the next permutation is supposed to be **2413**, but this program gives the previous permutation **4231** instead. How I can generate the next permutation *i+1*, given *i?*

```
public class SJTAlgorithm {


    private int[] dir;

    // Constructor to initialize the directions
    public SJTAlgorithm(int n) {
        dir = new int[n];
        // Initially, all directions are set to -1 (left).
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            dir[i] = -1;
        }
    }
    // Function to check if an integer is mobile
    private static boolean isMobile(int[] permutation, int[] dir, int index) {
        int nextIndex = index + dir[index];
        // An integer is mobile if the next index is within bounds and
        // the adjacent integer in the direction it's moving is smaller.
        return nextIndex >= 0 && nextIndex < permutation.length && permutation[index] > permutation[nextIndex];
    }

    // Function to find the largest mobile integer
    private static int getMobileIndex(int[] permutation, int[] dir) {
        int mobilePrev = 0, mobileIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < permutation.length; i++) {
            if (isMobile(permutation, dir, i) && permutation[i] > mobilePrev) {
                mobilePrev = permutation[i];
                mobileIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return mobileIndex;
    }

    // Function to find the next permutation
    public static int[] nextPermutation(int[] permutation) {
        int n = permutation.length;
        int[] dir = new int[n];

        // Initially, all directions are set to -1 (left).
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            dir[i] = -1;
        }

        // Find the largest mobile integer in the permutation.
        int mobileIndex = getMobileIndex(permutation, dir);
        if (mobileIndex == -1) { // No mobile integer means this is the last permutation.
            return null;
        }

        // Swap the mobile integer with the adjacent integer in its current direction.
        int swapIndex = mobileIndex + dir[mobileIndex];
        int temp = permutation[mobileIndex];
        permutation[mobileIndex] = permutation[swapIndex];
        permutation[swapIndex] = temp;

        // Change the direction of all integers larger than the current mobile integer.
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (permutation[i] > permutation[swapIndex]) {
                dir[i] = -dir[i];
            }
        }

        return permutation;
    }

    // Main function to test the algorithm
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] permutation = {4, 2, 1, 3};
        SJTAlgorithm sjt = new SJTAlgorithm(permutation.length); // Initialize the SJTAlgorithm instance
        int[] nextPerm = sjt.nextPermutation(permutation);

        if (nextPerm != null) {
            System.out.println("Next permutation:");
            for (int num : nextPerm) {
                System.out.print(num + " ");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No next permutation available (last permutation reached).");
        }
    }
}

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TajXb.jpg
```

Comment: Have you studied the [Wikipedia article on the SJT Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm)?

Answer (score 0):

The **Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter** (SJT) algorithm generates permutations by performing a series of swaps based on the direction of each element. Here's an example of how you can implement the SJT algorithm in C++ to generate the next permutation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// Function to find the largest mobile integer in a given permutation
int findLargestMobile(const std::vector<int>& perm, const std::vector<int>& dir) {
    int maxMobile = 0;
    int mobileIndex = -1;
    const int size = perm.size();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (((dir[i] == -1) && (i > 0) && (perm[i] > perm[i - 1])) ||
            ((dir[i] == 1) && (i < size - 1) && (perm[i] > perm[i + 1]))) {
            if (perm[i] > maxMobile) {
                maxMobile = perm[i];
                mobileIndex = i;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return mobileIndex;
}

// Function to generate the next permutation using the Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm
void generateNextPermutation(std::vector<int>& permutation) {
    int size = permutation.size();
    std::vector<int> direction(size, -1); // -1 represents left direction
    
    // Find the largest mobile integer
    int mobileIndex = findLargestMobile(permutation, direction);
    
    if (mobileIndex != -1) {
        int mobileElement = permutation[mobileIndex];
        int dir = direction[mobileIndex];
        
        // Swap the mobile element with the adjacent element in its direction
        std::swap(permutation[mobileIndex], permutation[mobileIndex + dir]);
        std::swap(direction[mobileIndex], direction[mobileIndex + dir]);
        
        // Reverse the direction of all elements greater than the mobile element
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            if (permutation[i] > mobileElement) {
                direction[i] *= -1;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Function to print a permutation
void printPermutation(const std::vector<int>& permutation) {
    for (int num : permutation) {
        std::cout << num << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> permutation = {1, 2, 3}; // Change this permutation as needed
    
    std::cout << "Current permutation: ";
    printPermutation(permutation);
    
    generateNextPermutation(permutation);
    
    std::cout << "Next permutation: ";
    printPermutation(permutation);
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Answer**:

```
Current permutation: 4 2 1 3 
Next permutation: 4 2 3 1
```

**Reason**:

The **Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter** algorithm follows this structure: the sequence of permutations it generates consists of
`(n-1)!` blocks of permutations, so that within each block the permutations agree on the ordering of the numbers from `1` to `n-1` and differ only in the position of `n`. The blocks themselves are ordered recursively, according to the Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm for one less element.

the positions in which n is placed occur either in descending or ascending order, and the blocks alternate between these two orders: the placements of n in the first block are in descending order, in the second block they are in ascending order, in the third block they are in descending order, and so on.

Thus, from the single permutation on one element,

```
1
```

one may place the number 2 in each possible position in descending order to form a list of two permutations on two elements,

```
1 2
2 1
```

Then, one may place the number 3 in each of three different positions for these two permutations, in descending order for the first permutation 1 2, and then in ascending order for the permutation 2 1:

```
1 2 3
1 3 2
3 1 2
3 2 1
2 3 1
2 1 3
```

To learn more check:

1. [Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm)
2. [Comparative Study on the Performance
   of Permutation Algorithms](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1205/1205.2888.pdf)

**Time Complexity**:
The time complexity of generating the next permutation using the Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm is O(n), where n is the length of the input sequence to permute 12. The algorithm generates all permutations of a sequence by swapping just two adjacent elements of the sequence. Therefore, to generate the next permutation, we only need to swap two adjacent elements in the sequence.

Here what your looking for:

```
4213
4231
4321
3421
3412
3142
1342
1324
1234
2134
2143
2413 
/* 2413 This is what you expected but you won't find the result using next permutation algorithm go for all permutation using SJT*/
```

To find all permutation -> [Find all permutation using SJT](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/johnson-trotter-algorithm/)

I hope this helps!

Comment: This does give the correct answer input "4213". ✅ However, for input "1342", the program should output "3124", but it instead outputs "1432".
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TajXb.jpg

Comment: This algorithm will only work for finding the next permutation using SJT. If you want to find all the possible permutation of a given numbers this algorithm will not work.

Comment: This answer looks like (mostly) a copy-paste from ChatGPT

Answer (score 0):

Upon further inspection, it is not possible to generate the next permutation i+1 given a permutation i. This is because the program has no way of knowing what the directions of the permutation i numbers are by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following recursion:

Start with your permutation P with n elements:

Step 1: If n == 1 then you are done as you are at the end of all possible permutations. There is no "Next permutation".

Step 2: If n > 1 search the largest element X of your permutation P, ignore X for a moment and calculate the parity p(P') of the permutation P' represented by the n-1 remaining elements. If p(P') is odd then X will go right and if p(P') is even then X will go left. If X can move in P then move (swap) and you are done.

Step 3: If X can't move, because it is inside P already most right (and p(P') = odd) or most left (and p(P') = even) then go with P' to step 1. (In this case the elements of P' are placed in direct line as the elements of P have been in direct line and the omitted X is on the margin.)

For permutation parity calculation you may look here:
[Efficiently determine the parity of a permutation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702782/efficiently-determine-the-parity-of-a-permutation)

This algorithm is close or equivalent to the description under "Original Version" in [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm)